# How to set the default location of an open file dialog to the program location

Tags: vb.net, openfiledialog

I've got a vb.net application which is almost ready to deploy, but I need to add one final feature.

When the program gets installed, a blank database is going to be installed with it. On the program log on screen, there is a textbox that has the location of the database, with one button to change the location (Which opens an OpenFileDialog), and then a button to save the new location into the .ini file.

What I want to do is: when the program is first installed and opened, I want the 'Explore' button (which opens the OFD) to open it pointing to the Databases folder which is created in the setup, so that the user doesn't have to keep searching for the database in their PC.

Eg; Say I deploy the application on my PC, and the location I install it to is: C:\Desktop, I need the OFD to point at C:\Desktop\Deploy\Databases

But this obviously will change depending on where the user installs it. How can this be done?

Comment: `Environment.GetFolderPath()`  will give you access to all the special folders including `Users` and `AppData`.  You could create such a pth and store the db there, and not have to bother the user with where your data is stored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Application.StartupPath` to refer to the folder path of your program folder, so you would use `Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "Deploy\Databases")` as the full folder path in that case.